# Unable to run processing pde file in Sublime Text

Tags: processing, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am trying to run an example file from the Hype framework in Sublime Text and when I hit Ctrl + B I get "Could not create the output folder".

Any thoughts?

Link to example code:
http://www.hypeframework.org/examples/HOscillator/example_001/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your build system under `Tools > Build System > Processing`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have put the .pde file in a folder that matches it's name..

ex. myGame.pde must be in a folder called, myGame.